# Rails 4 respond_to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller, format

I have a simple PagesController with a 'homepage' method.
I just want the method to respond to my homepage.js.erb template file which is containing a simple `console.log("Hello World!");`
So i wrote `respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.html
        end`
in my homepage method but it does nothing. ( no `hello world` in my chrome console ).
If i remove the `format.html` rails throw me this error `"ActionController::UnknownFormat"`.

Is it a problem with turbolinks? how can i do?

Thanks JD

Answer (score 0):

Turbolinks sends request as Html, So the js file wont get rendered but HTML one and on Client side turbolinks just replaces body with new content and updates URL.

If you want to render you js.erb file then you need to initiate js request not html. just write remote true in link_to.

Example

```
= link_to 'XYZ', url, :remote => true
```

Or if you want to execute js code on browser for HTML request then you need to write your JavaScript code inside you HTML file(format.html)

Example:

```
javascript:
  console.log("Hello World!");
```